Ripping Audio-CD to FLAC using EAC and FFMPEG
I'm using EAC to rip Audio-CDs and convert the files using the FLAC.exe commandline
-V -8 -T "ALBUM=%albumtitle%" -T "ALBUMARTIST=%albumartist%" -T "DATE=%year%" -T "GENRE=%genre%" -T "COMMENT=%comment%" -T "DISCTOTAL=%totalcds%" -T "TOTALDISCS=%totalcds%" -T "DISCNUMBER=%cdnumber%/%totalcds%" -T "TRACKTOTAL=%numtracks%" -T "TOTALTRACKS=%numtracks%" -T "COMPOSER=%composer%" %haslyrics%--tag-from-file=LYRICS="%lyricsfile%"%haslyrics% %hascover%--picture="%coverfile%"%hascover% -T "ARTIST=%artist%" -T "TRACKNUMBER=%tracknr%" -T "TITLE=%title%" %source% -o %dest%
I wanted to see if I can use FFMPEG to compress to FLAC and tried to construct a command line that included all the metadata and a cover image. I wanted to test the string, pasted it into the input field "Additional command-line options" and noticed it got truncated after 500 characters. My string is 700 characters long.
-y -i %source% %hascover%-i "%coverfile%" -map 0:a -map 1%hascover% -threads 4 -c:a flac -compression_level 12 %hascover%-c:v copy-metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" -disposition:1 attached_pic-metadata%hascover% "ALBUM=%albumtitle%" -metadata "ALBUM_ARTIST=%albumartist%" -metadata "DATE=%year%" -metadata "GENRE=%genre%" -metadata "COMMENT=%comment%" -metadata "DISCTOTAL=%totalcds%" -metadata "TOTALDISCS=%totalcds%" -metadata "DISCNUMBER=%cdnumber%/%totalcds%" -metadata "TRACKTOTAL=%numtracks%" -metadata "TOTALTRACKS=%numtracks%" -metadata "COMPOSER=%composer%" -metadata "ARTIST=%artist%" -metadata "TRACKNUMBER=%tracknr%" -metadata "TITLE=%title%" %dest%
Is there a known limit of 500 characters for the command line in EAC?
How would a command line look that compresses ripped audio to FLAC using FFMPEG that includes an image and all the metadata?
There is this sample on hydrogenaud.io that unfortunately does not save an image.
